# Initializing ArrayList with constant literal

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

Can the ArrayList below be initialized directly without the need for aFileExt string array?

```
private static string[] aFileExt = 
     {"css", "gif", "htm", "html", "txt", "xml" };
private System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes =
     new System.Collections.ArrayList(aFileExt);
```

The line below is the goal, but my .Net Compiler does not like it:

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes = 
     new System.Collections.ArrayList({"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

I am using the .net Micro Framework and thus do not have access to generic types.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

C# 1 or 2:

```
private static ArrayList alFileTypes = 
     new ArrayList(new string[] {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

C# 3 using an implicitly typed array:

```
private static ArrayList alFileTypes = 
    new ArrayList(new[] {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

C# 3 using a collection initializer:

```
private static ArrayList alFileTypes = 
    new ArrayList{"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"};
```

Or create your own helper method:

```
public static ArrayList CreateList(params object[] items)
{
    return new ArrayList(items);
}
```

then:

```
static ArrayList alFileTypes = CreateList("css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml");
```

Any reason why you're not using the generic collections, btw?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes, generics and many of the System.Collections are not supported in my version of .net.

Comment: @MandoMando: For a question like this it's probably worth stating which version of .NET you're using, and which version of C#.

Comment: The C# 3 collection initializer is the solution for me because: 

1. it compiles on my (special) version of .net
2. does not create a new object.  (memory is an issue in this case)

Comment: Jon, I didn't mention my version of .net somewhat intentionally because it's in beta and changing, and there are very few folks around world that use netmf v4.0.

Comment: @MandoMando: It would still have been useful information. For example, if you knew you could use C# 3 features even without generics, that would have told us that a collection initializer would be a good way to go.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Knowing the version info would have saved you time.   I honestly cannot make any factual claims about the version of C# supported (it's up to MS .Net team to call that when they're ready).  Though I did know that generics are not supported and thought it's unrelated.  

Based on the responses to my new-to-the-site post, I now know to include all helpful info :)

Many thanks for providing solutions for all versions.  Which was indeed what I was looking to feed the compiler.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using .NET 2.0 or greater, you should be using the generic `List<T>` type (even if it's `List<object>`, which would given you the same functionality as `ArrayList`).

If you're using .NET 3.5 or greater, you can use this syntax:

```
private static List<string> fileTypes = new List<string>()
{ 
    "css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml" 
};
```

Either way, however, if you want to stick with `ArrayList`, you can just do:

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes = 
 new System.Collections.ArrayList(new object[] {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

Comment: +1 for using List<T> instead or ArrayList (and still answering the original question).

Comment: Actually, my version of .Net Generics are not supported.

Answer (score 10):

C# 3.0 with a generic `List<T>`, rather than an `ArrayList` :

```
private static List<string> alFileTypes =
    new List<string> {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"};
```

Comment: Excellent! But to compile, the LHS would need to be of type List<string>: `private static List<string> alFileTypes = new List<string> {"css", ...`

Comment: @Rubistro, indeed... I just forgot to replace "ArrayList" ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes = 
 new System.Collections.ArrayList(new string [] {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes =   new System.Collections.ArrayList(){"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"};
```

Comment: I thought this was clever, too.  In my mind it didn't even look like it was going to compile :)
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, just change

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes = 
     new System.Collections.ArrayList({"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```

to

```
private static System.Collections.ArrayList alFileTypes = 
     new System.Collections.ArrayList(new string[] {"css","gif","htm","html","txt","xml"});
```